# How do I read in a text file and print them out to a file in Prolog?

Tags: io, prolog, dcg

I have a text file, and I want to read it in and print them out in screen and write them into a new output file. So what I have done so far is

```
main :-
    open('text.txt', read, ID),  % open a stream
    repeat,             % try again forever
    read(ID, X),        % read from the stream
    write(X), nl,       % write to current output stream
    X == end_of_file,   % fail (backtrack) if not end of 
    !,
    close(ID).
```

But I only received an error message like,

```
ERROR: text.txt:1:0: Syntax error: Operator expected
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

`read/2` reads valid Prolog text. The message suggests, that in line 1 of text.txt you have some invalid Prolog text.  Maybe a couple of words separated by spaces.

If you want to read regular text, you can do it very low-level using `get_char/2`, or you might want to do it more high level using grammars. SWI-Prolog has `library(pio)` for that.

Here is the Prolog programmer's equivalent to `grep -q`.

```
?- phrase_from_file((...,"root",...),'/etc/passwd').
   true
;  true
;  true
;  false.
```

Actually, that's rather `grep -c`.

You need to load following definition for it:

```
... --> [] | [_], ... .
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a reusable snippet:

```
%%  file_atoms(File, Atom) is nondet.
%
%   read each line as atom on backtrack
%
file_atoms(File, Atom) :-
    open(File, read, Stream),
    repeat,
    read_line_to_codes(Stream, Codes),
    (   Codes \= end_of_file
    ->  atom_codes(Atom, Codes)
    ;   close(Stream), !, fail
    ).
```

This calls read_line_to_codes, a SWI-Prolog builtin.

Answer (score 0):

```
is_eof(FlHndl, CharCode, CurrentLine, FileAkku, FileContent) :-
        CharCode == -1,
        append(FileAkku, [CurrentLine], FileContent),
        close(FlHndl), !.

is_newline(FlHndl, CharCode, CurrentLine, FileAkku, FileContent) :-
        CharCode == 10,
        append(FileAkku, [CurrentLine], NextFileAkku),
        read_loop(FlHndl, '', NextFileAkku, FileContent).

append_char(FlHndl, CharCode, CurrentLine, FileAkku, FileContent) :-
        char_code(Char, CharCode),
        atom_concat(CurrentLine, Char, NextCurrentLine),
         read_loop(FlHndl, NextCurrentLine, FileAkku, FileContent).

read_file(FileName, FileContent) :-
        open(FileName, read, FlHndl),
        read_loop(FlHndl, '', [], FileContent), !.

read_loop(FlHndl, CurrentLine, FileAkku, FileContent) :-
        get_code(FlHndl, CharCode),
        ( is_eof(FlHndl, CharCode, CurrentLine, FileAkku, FileContent)
        ; is_newline(FlHndl, CharCode, CurrentLine, FileAkku, FileContent)
        ; append_char(FlHndl, CharCode, CurrentLine, FileAkku, FileContent)).

main(InputFile, OutputFile) :-
    open(OutputFile, write, OS),
    (   read_file(InputFile,InputLines),
        member(Line, InputLines),
        write(Line), nl,
        write(OS,Line),nl(OS),
        false
        ;
        close(OS)
    ).
```

So, you can use it like `main('text.txt', 'output.txt').`